# Packaging a single JAR file as an RPM properly

Tags: java, linux, rpm

I've create a Java JAR file successfully. I now want to package my JAR file as an RPM (RedHat Package Manager) so that I can make it installable for Linux.

What would be the proper way to package a single JAR file as an RPM?

Answer (score 12):

If you're using Maven there's the [maven rpm plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/).

Comment: Is there any such option for ANT based builds?

Comment: @TechEnthusiast - I would not know, sorry.